# error install jigsaw on linux with java

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to install Jigsaw on Linux. I have installed on my machine JDK.here is the message of java -version:

java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)

I followed your instructions but when I execute install.sh I receive:

./install.sh: 5: cd: can't cd to Jigsaw
Errore: impossibile trovare o caricare la classe principale Install

So I choose the manual way exporting CLASSPATH but when I execute java Install here it is the message

> Jigsaw/2.2.6 setup.
>
> updating /home/mazzy/Scaricati/Jigsaw/Jigsaw/config/http-server.props ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/jigsaw/http/httpd
>     at Install.install(Install.java:134)
>     at Install.main(Install.java:210)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.jigsaw.http.httpd
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
>     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
>     ... 2 more